# Not able to resolve stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: selenium, dom, staleelementreferenceexception

I'm getting stale element exception and tried adding try catch block but still i'm getting this error. Is there a way to resolve it? I want to click on particular link in each div which contains the text "Dep. Libraries".

```
        List<WebElement> lib = driver.findElements(By.className("row"));
        ListIterator<WebElement> listlib = lib.listIterator();
        System.out.println(listlib);
        while(listlib.hasNext()) {
             WebElement elem = listlib.next();
             List<WebElement> sub = elem.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='column sp']"));
             ListIterator<WebElement> listsub = sub.listIterator();
             while(listsub.hasNext()) {
                WebElement elem1 = listsub.next();          
                if((elem1.getText()).contains("Dep. Libraries")) {          
                elem1.click();
                break;
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: what is error pls edit your question

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to resolve stale element error

1. Refresh page before interect element (Use Refresh();)
2. Try to loop until the particular element capture

Comment: Thanks, I tried both ways but still no luck. I want to click on each element stored in listsub.